# Module of differentials of $R=k[x,y]/(x^3+y^2-1)$ is locally free of rank $1$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic not $2$ or $3$, and let $R=k[x,y]/(x^3+y^2-1)$. Show that $\Omega_{R/k}$ is a locally free module of rank $1$.

This is not hard when $k$ is perfect or given the condition for the prime $P\supset I$, the residue class field $\operatorname{Frac}(k[x,y]/P)$ is separable over $k$. But here we don't have such assumptions, I wonder how to deduce the result for such general $k$. Or the $k$ must be perfect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\Omega_{R/k}$ has an explicit presentation as $M=R\langle dx,dy\rangle /(3x^2dx+2ydy)$ (ref [00RM](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00RM)). For $x\neq 0$, we see that $dx=\frac{2y}{3x^2}dy$ and $M_x$ is free over $R_x$; similarly for $y\neq 0$ we see that $dy=\frac{3x^2}{2y}dx$ and therefore $M_y$ is free over $R_y$. Since these two open sets cover $\operatorname{Spec} R$, we're good.